# Difference between HTML gear and Salesforce Lead form gear on Cloud Pages?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I'm trying to figure out the difference between the HTML gear and Salesforce Lead Form gear on Cloud Pages.  Both gears drop an empty HTML box where you paste HTML code in.  I pasted the web-to-lead form from Salesforce into each gear, and both function the same.  What's the difference between the two?

Comment: There's no difference other than the way it's displayed within the layers menu, which is a helpful way to designate it.  Both function as HTML blocks

Comment: @TomCallahan I can mark this as the answer if you want to put it as the answer.  Thanks, that definitely answered my question!

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference other than the way it's displayed within the layers menu, which is a helpful way to designate it. Both function as HTML blocks.

If you have access, I'd recommend using the `Content Builder` editor instead of Classic Editor.  It's a bit more friendly on the eyes.